# Upper triangular part of tensor

Tags: matrix, tensors

I have created a random real antisymmetric matrix as

```
n = 4;
dist = NormalDistribution[];
s = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i < j :> RandomVariate[dist], {n, n}];
m = Normal[s - Transpose[s]]
```

Now I can take the upper part of the matrix using the code
takeUpper1[mat_?SquareMatrixQ] :=

```
 Join @@ Table[
    mat[[i, j]], {i, Length[mat]}, {j, i + 1, Length[mat]}];

fnew = takeUpper1[m]
```

If I created the tensor product of two m matrices as:

```
ss1 = m\[TensorProduct]m
```

If I get the result as:
[image: dd]

Can I take the upper triangular part of each individual block and form a new matrix as:
[image: dd]

Comment: The upper triangular part of a 4*4-matrix is a 6-vector. What you have with the tensor product is a 4*4 block-matrix where the blocks themselves are 4*4 matrices. If you apply the upper triangulation to each block, (using `Map[takeUpper1, ss1, {2}]`) what you get in the end is a 4*4 matrix of 6-vectors. Ie. a 4*4*6 tensor. So it doesn't quite have matrix structure. 

You can get a 16*16 matrix with `ArrayFlatten[ss1]` . Also, if you contract the tensor product with `TensorContract[ss1,{{2,3}}]`, the result is the ordinary matrix multiplication `m.m` .

Comment: The upper triangular part of a 4x4 matrix is a 6-vector.  True. There are 16 such matrices though and the output should have 16 rows. I think the original query should be modified to read "strict upper triangular part of each of the matrices in the strict upper triangular part of ss1".